# Objective C Exception during file reading?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, exception, osx-lion

I am trying to read a text file line by line, and the text file will be a really small file so I just used:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

However, an exception is raised on that line, saying:

```
[NSURL getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f92c40e1890
```

I'm really new to Objective-C and I don't get why this is happening...

Thanks in advance.

---

```
NSString *filePath;
NSOpenPanel *fileBrowser = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[fileBrowser setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[fileBrowser setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
if ([fileBrowser runModal] == NSOKButton) {
    NSArray *files = [fileBrowser URLs];
    for ( int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ ) {
        filePath = [files objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Is this because of the [fileBrowser URLs] part?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that you created filePath as a NSURL when you shouldn't have. Please post the code for creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `filePath` is an `NSURL`, but `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` expects the path as an `NSString`.

Try this:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: YES, this worked. But I just decided to convert the url to an NSString for the filepath. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `NSURL` does not have a method `getFileSystemRespresentation`, this is in `NSString`.

You can either use this method on your `fileContents` string, or pass your `fileContents` string to `NSURL`'s `URLWithString` method.

Comment: Yes.. now I get it. Thank you!